# How do you install packetfence?

Tags: 10.10, server

Was anyone able to install packetfence on Ubuntu 10.10? I tried a [tutorial](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/386610%3ainstall-packetfence-for-powerful-network-access-control), but didn't have any luck. Some of the services installed and are working apache with php, snort, pfdetect, and pfdhcplistener. I can even get info from it, but for the life of me I can't get it to work with apache2.

When I run `pfcmd service pf start` I also get an error `uninitialized value $_[7] in join at /usr/local/pf/lib/pf/class.pm line 170`

Comment: according to a thread on the packetfence-users list this is a normal warning message: http://www.mail-archive.com/packetfence-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00205.html

Comment: cross posted here: http://serverfault.com/questions/221128/installing-packetfence

Comment: btw the tutorial you linked to specifically notes that it doesn't work with web administration after 9.04 - "If you are working with Ubuntu 9.04 or earlier, you will be able to work with the Web-based system, but any release later than 9.04 and you are stuck with the command line."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work on the PacketFence project

It's complicated because of the interaction between PacketFence and the system components (apache, snmptrapd, named, dhcpd). As soon as the configuration files are not located in the same locations (`/etc/httpd/` vs `/etc/apache2/`) we run into problems. It is not only a packaging issue, the code will have to be patched.

However, good timing for you, it's something we want to tackle soon. Here's a ticket where you can track our progress:
http://www.packetfence.org/bugs/view.php?id=1067

There will also be pointers to what is working and what is not. Feel free to chip in and help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like packetfence and it's related modules, needs to be packages for Debian. This isn't a hard job, since a lot of the modules are available with standard perl installers. But it would require each module to be built.

Once you've got a nice package of packetfence made up, you can apply the patch suggested in the tutorial which enables apache2 configuration.

I think that the web interface for packetfence needs upgrading to work with apache2 if it doesn't already work. This probably requires the attention of a developer.

Don't be shy asking for (or paying for) developers and packagers to help you get this installable for everyone. It's obviously something that needs doing:

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/78